# single modular component should work with other components (component=module)

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have a question but I am not sure how to describe it properly so please read carefuly.
First, lets define the term module in my eyes:
module = bunch of classes, interfaces enums (and so on) intended for solving single problem.
For example:

- module that intended to handle Working Arrangement
- module that intended to handle Bookkeeping

Today our application have bookkeepping module that intended to hanlde the whole bokkeepping need in the application.
We also have ModuleA that produces items that should be later used in the bookkeepping module in order to create invoices from them.
So, in order to let those two modules contact between each other - we actually didn't consider the both modules as modules and each module knows classes from the other module.
For example:

- In Bookkeepping module, if I need to load all the items in order to create invoice, I use directly the class responsible the items from moduleA.
- In order to follow items that have invoices in moduleA, I stored the id of the invoice (the invoice relates to bookkeeping module) in the items table.

As you can see there is a real bond betwen those two wannabe "modules".

Now we got another need.
We also have moduleB and we need to use moduleB also with the bookkeeping. But, as I described earlier, bookeeping only knows items from moduleA and know how to interact with them and only with them.

How can we make the bookkeeping module generic/modularic enough so that we can use other modules also with it?
Lets assume I manage to separate somehow moduleA, moduleB and bookkeeping, and lets assume bookkeeping doesn't know the other modules. There must be someone who knows all the modules in order to connect between them! Who will connect between moduleB and the bookkeeping?

I really appriciate possible architecture solutions, diagrams and links to relevant information I should know.

Thank you very much,
Naor

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question correctly then I believe the issue you are running into relates to the DDD concept of [bounded contexts](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/91). It seems that you have a bookkeeping context and another context which may trigger bookkeeping events. The DDD way of solving this problem is to create a different model for each context. For example, suppose that Module A is a products context, it contains the domain model for products for sale. Within this context there are many aspects related to products, product descriptions, pricing, etc. Specifically, products in this context are [entities](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/109). From the perspective of the bookkeeping context, the notion of product manifests itself as an invoice line item. The only aspects of a product that are important to the bookkeeping context are the product ID and the price at the time of invoicing. Products are likely not entities in this context by [value objects](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/135). Since the notion of a product is different for each context, a different model should be created. The only thing shared is the product ID so that it can be known which product is being referred to by the bookkeeping context.

Factoring the system in this way solves many other problems which arise when disparate contexts are cramped into the same model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am going to look for more info and examples about bounded contexts on the web. But in your answer both of the modules/contexts moduleA and moduleB share the same id. This is something I can't afford. Do you have any idea how to workaround?

Comment: are there any practical example or tips?

Comment: What I meant by share ID is that if there is a product entity in Module A, it would have some sort of ID value, such as a Guid or a database generated sequential int. Then, suppose the bookkeeping module needs to refer to products as line items in an invoice. That reference should be made using the same ID value, not the entire object model. Can you explain why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Thats won't work because the following: Assume moduleA has product with id=1 and moduleB has also product(or something else that require bookkeeping) with id=1. Then there is a question in the bokkeeping module - what is the module of an item with id=1?

Comment: Why does the bookkeeping module need to know which module the ID comes from? If you have a bookkeeping module that deals with entities from two different modules, for example products from module A and subscriptions from module B, then you can either share the concept of a product between module A and B so that the ID is unique, or enforce uniqueness by pre-pending a module specific prefix to the ID that gets passed to bookkeeping module.

Comment: What do you think about this: moduleA has products and moduleB has subscriptions. The bookkeeping module has an abstract (or not abstract) class that define a bokkeeping item. there will be also a bookkeeping "gate" class that will know moduleA and moduleB and will suppliy items to the bokkeeping module according to the products and subscriptions from the modules A,B.
How does it sound?

Comment: Another thing, someone must know both moduleA, moduleB and bookkeeping module in order to load the items and cal the bookkeeping invoice creator. Who will it be? To whom will it belong?